# How to do a conditional boosting in solr with edismax parser

Tags: solr

I want to boost something like this 
boost by factor of 100 at query time if color:silver AND brand:apple. What will be the bf or bf syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bq` ([Boost Query](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/the-dismax-query-parser.html#bq-boost-query-parameter)) parameter instead of bf for this kind of things :

```
bq=(color:silver AND brand:apple)^100
```